# How to Test Validation Rule Programmatically in VBA/Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, validationrule

I have the validation rules set in the design table and I want to test it before I save the changes done in the recordset.

Comment: are you using access forms to enter the data? how is the data entered?

Comment: yes, I'm using Access form. the data is entered via bound form. the validation rules are saved in the form's source table, not in the form's controls.

Answer (score -1):

Use a form to enter the data.

Then use the same validation rules in the BeforeInsert and BeforeUpdate events of the form.

Comment: yes but, how to test the validation rules programmatically? eg:                  if ( TestValidationRule(control.Value, recordset.ValidationRule) ) then recordset.Update                                                                                           notice that I refer to the recordset's validation rule, not the control's one.

Comment: You can in the control properties replicate the validation rule for the field ans also specify a message. However, it far more flexible to use the BeforeUpdate and/or BeforeInsert events. Set Cancel = True in case of a validation error.

Comment: hi Gustav. thanks for you assistance. I got it without replicating the validation rule. I'm still working on the code so I didn't post it here yet. I access the table's field validation rule via recordset properties and test it programmatically. if the test returns true, I save the changes done in the recordset (recordset.Update). if it returns false, I run a message box showing the validation text also got thru the recordset (recordset.Fields(control.RecordSource).ValidationText). it is working fine for me.